# PHP - fopen($url) failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, fopen

I have to website with a very similar php configuration (actually on the same hosting account), with almost identical php code and with identical file structure. At some point, I call *fopen(http://example.com/rssfedd.xml)* to retrieve a RSS feed.

on http://sfdmorin.com/accueil/index.php everything works fine, on http://danielpoiriergda.ca/accueil/index.php i get:

> Warning: fopen(http://affaires.lapresse.ca/rss/2399.xml)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/vhosts/danielpoiriergda.ca/httpdocs/snippet/lastRSS.php on
>   line 143

```
  $f = fopen("http://affaires.lapresse.ca/rss/2399.xml", 'r');
```

Both website **have php debug mode enabled** and both have the **same permissions for file and folders.**
Both info.php have ***allow_url_fopen* enabled** for local and master value

Here are the major differences I found on both phpinfo() file:

not working site: Server API    CGI/FastCGI

working site: Server API    Apache 2.0 Handler

and on the working site there are no php.ini file in the path given by the *loaded configuration file* field

EDIT:
I know this thread is probably dead, but not the problem.
I check, with Netbeans fill diff, all the PHP code and php.ini are exactly the same on both domain.

I know similar questions were ask, but they did not help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Check if safe_mode is turned on, this disables allow_url_fopen

Comment: safe_mode was on.  I tried turning it off and it still did not work

Comment: Check my comment again, "this disables allow_url_fopen", ask your hoster to turn it off - if they won't (why else did they switch it on?) then start using cURL to grab files for you...  check it is installed though.

Comment: Maybe a firewall-related issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I contacted my webserver tech support and they solve the problem. They did by:

> adding an exception to SELinux

I dont have a clue wwhat SELinux is or what they did specificaly.

Comment: Bumping an old thread here, but figured I'd comment on what they actually did. There is a flag in SELinux called "httpd_can_network_connect" which is set to Off by default. It needs to be set to on. Use `getsebool -a | grep http` to find what yours is. If it's set to Off, use `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`.